# Inserting XML data to JSON array in Index.php

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

sorry if this is a dumb question, I am just feeling lost here. I am trying to get certain values from my XML file to a JSON array in my plain PHP file.

So this is how i gather my XML file data and how my JSON is displayed depending on which case is true:

```
switch ($creditId) {
case 123:
    $xml = new XMLReader;
    $xml->open('123.xml');

    $doc = new DOMDocument;


    while ($xml->read() && $xml->name !== 'Decision');


    while ($xml->name === 'Decision')
    {


        $node = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($xml->expand(), 
true));

        $reason_text = $node->Reason->ReasonText ;
        echo "$reason_text \n";

        // go to next <DecisionResponse>
        $xml->next('Decision');
    }


        echo '[{
            "creditId": 123,
            "client": "Peter",
            "Decision": "Solo" ,
            "Factors": ["REASONTEXT1","REASONTEXT2"]
    }]';

    break;
case 789:

 $xml = new XMLReader;
    $xml->open('789.xml');

    $doc = new DOMDocument;


    while ($xml->read() && $xml->name !== 'Decision');


      while ($xml->name === 'Decision')
       {


        $node = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($xml->expand(), 
true));

        $reason_text = $node->Reason->ReasonText ;
        echo "$reason_text \n";

        // go to next <DecisionResponse>
        $xml->next('Decision');
       }


    echo '[{
        "creditId": 789,
        "client": "Jonas",
        "Decision": "Random",
        "Factors": ["REASONTEXT1","REASONTEXT2"]
    }]';
    break;
default:
    http_response_code(404);
}
```

REASONTEXT1 AND REASONTEXT2 is where the values of a variable $reason_text should be displayed in the JSON array. For instance: my json display of a 123 case now looks like this (echo of $reason_text outputs values RandomReason1 and RandomReason2):

```
 RandomReason1 
 RandomReason2
    [{
            "creditId": 123,
            "client": "Peter",
            "Decision": "Solo",
            "Factors": ["REASONTEXT1","REASONTEXT2"]
    }]
```

I want these values to be displayed like this:

```
    [{
            "creditId": 123,
            "client": "Peter",
            "Decision": "Solo",
            "Factors": ["RandomReason1","RandomReason2"]
    }]
```

To conclude, I want to insert certain XML data into a JSON array. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that this is a php question, not vue or js related. Now your code. It's printing the RandomReason1 and RandomReason2 before the json because you have this `echo "$reason_text \n";` on your code, you should print it just inside your json. 
So, store the values inside an array and then ECHO it just when you need.
e.g:

```
$reasons[] = $reason_text;
...
echo '[{
    "creditId": 789,
    "client": "Jonas",
    "Decision": "Random",
    "Factors": '.json_encode($ereasons).'
}]';
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty hard without your XML, but here we go :-)

Let's say your XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <Decision>
    <Reason>
      <ReasonText>This is my text #1</ReasonText>
    </Reason>
  </Decision>
  <Decision>
    <Reason>
      <ReasonText>This is my text #2</ReasonText>
    </Reason>
  </Decision>
</root>
```

I've made a working example for you for case 123:

```
        case 123:
            $xml = new XMLReader;
            $xml->open('123.xml');

            $doc = new DOMDocument;


            while ($xml->read()){
                $nodename=$xml->localName;
                $depth=$xml->depth;
                $gipchecked=0;
                if ($nodename=='Decision' &&  $xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT){ //EN van het type start elemenet
                        $node = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($xml->expand(),true));
                        $reason_text.= $node->Reason->ReasonText ;
                        echo "Reason text contains: $reason_text \r\n";
                }

                // go to next <DecisionResponse>
                // $xml->next('Decision');
            }
            $xml->close();


                echo '[{
                    "creditId": 123,
                    "client": "Peter",
                    "Decision": "Solo" ,
                    "Factors": '.json_encode($reason_text).'
            }]';

        break;
```

If you run that it will show the following result in your browser:

```
Reason text contains: This is my text #1 

Reason text contains: This is my text #1This is my text #2 

[{ "creditId": 123, "client": "Peter", "Decision": "Solo" , "Factors": "This is my text #1This is my text #2" }]
```

be sure to also close your xml at the end like so:

```
 $xml->close();
```

Beside that I would also take a good look at your case statements. In fact you need to change your file name (in case of 789 it becomes 789.xml) and the client + decision. You don't need to copy the part of XMLREADER for each case.

If you put that part dynamicly below your switch statements, you can do that once for alle cases. DRY or Don’t Repeat Yourself is a programming concept in software engineering, which tries to cut down redundancy from your code.
If you have the same code multiple times in your script and you're about to make an adjustement, changes are that you're going to forget to do it in other places. To try to avoid that!